# arguments passed to `npm start` are not recognized like the ones passed using `npm run start`

Tags: node.js

I have a simple npm script:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run start:dev",
    "start:dev": "node server.js"
  }
}
```

Inside `server.js` I have:

```
console.log(require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2)));
```

Running the following commands, these are the outputs:

```
$ npm start -- --test one
{ _: [ 'one' ] }

$ npm run start -- --test one
{ _: [], test: 'one' }
```

The second output is the one I'd like to have when I use `npm start`, why instead I get the first one?

Comment: Because arguments are only passed to the script/command that you run directly (`npm run start:dev`). They aren't miraculously propagated.

Comment: Exactly, but I'd expect the two commands to behave the same at least

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. But still, I can't reproduce your problem, both give the same result for me (the same as the first output in your question). Tested Node v4 and v6, npm v2 and v3.

Comment: I've reported it to npm and they reproduce it https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/12946

Comment: Here's what I'm seeing: https://gist.github.com/robertklep/0cad3fcc4bbf3c20cb349a4d941babe7

Comment: Obviously you should run the npm command that directly spawns the node instance to see any difference